# Can't write to Facebook group after receiving a message from bot

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-group

We have a game on Facebook instant games, a page for it and a server bot receiving gameplay events and sending messages to users (page_messaging).
When a user first opens Fb page (buttons Play game, Message, Like on the right), clicks a Message button, he may write an arbitrary message (textbox in message window).
But after the very first message from the server bot that textbox in messaging window disappears and a user can't write to a group any more - only receive messages.
Has anyone faced this issue with UI on Web?

Tried on Web and Messenger app on iOS - no textbox. But Messenger on masOS allows to post messages even after receiving from bot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.